# is WWDC 2018 sample code available online?

Tags: wwdc

I've looked through the forum and have noticed that similar questions have  generally been responded to as 'off-topic', as they "tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." I realize this might not be the correct place to discuss the rightness or wrongness of that decision, but I can't post my question on the meta site as I don't have sufficient reputation. Ergo I'm hoping by posting it here that I can gain sufficient rep to be able to post it there!

I realize this seems to be a rather convoluted way of doing things, but I can't figure out another way of doing it. If there is another way of being able to post to meta w/out having any reputation, please let me know!

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says questions asking us to find or recommend off-site resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Most WWDC 2018 sessions that include sample code will have the sample code available in the Resources associated with each session.

All of the WWDC 2018 video session are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2018/). For example, [Session 237](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/237/) provides a link to its [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/building_an_app_based_on_the_document_browser_view_controller).

ARKit 2: https://developer.apple.com/arkit/

As far as I can tell there is currently no consolidated page that lists all WWDC 2018 source code.

Comment: How do you search for other WWDC? (i.e 2019, 2020) Having a hard time navigating their website

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the first two parts of the demo project - the Column Flow Layout and the Mosaic Layout. I haven't updated the friends list yet.

https://github.com/calinraducalin/ATourOfCollectionView